# Programming VBA in an Outlook form

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I created my own Outlook form to use it as standard surface to enter certain orders instead of the normal message form. The creation, editing and sending works perfectly fine and in the next step I want to insert some code via VBA.
My problem is that I can´t access the objects of my form in the VBA editor. E.g. I want to show a message box when a certain checkbox is checked. According code would be:

```
Sub example()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
MsgBox("Checkbox 1 is checked.")
End If
End Sub
```

When I run the code I get the error that the object could not be found. The same goes for every other object, like textboxes or labels etc.
I guess the solution is pretty simple, like putting *Item.* or sth. like that in front of each object. But so far I wasn't able to find the solution.

I´m using Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year too late but you'll want to do something like this example below. It's kinda a work around but you can get whatever value was selected.

```
Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Set objPage = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Message")
    Set Control = objPage.Controls("ComboBox1")

    MsgBox "The value in the " & Control.Name & _
           "control has changed to " & Control.Value & "."
End Sub
```

You should be able to get the value, just get a handle on the object you want using the Inspector

Answer (score 0):

The following is an excerpt from [here](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/04/24/creating-custom-outlook-forms/)

> When you use a custom form, Outlook only supports the Click event for
>   controls. This is a natural choice for buttons but not optimal for
>   controls like the combo box. You write the code by inserting it into a
>   form’s VBScript editor. You need to have the Outlook form open in the
>   Form Designer and click the View Code button found in the Form group
>   of the Developer tab.

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
  msgbox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

The code page is fairly minimal with no syntax highlighting. I just tried this now and it does work. Dont forget to Publish your form to pick up the new changes.

Comment: So it´s actually not possible to access the attributes of the obejcts themselves (like visibility, color etc.)? And I can´t use the VBA Editor at all?

Comment: The site only suggests that it only responds to the one event but if you keep reading it shows you some information for another event. I would imagine control properties are accessible and there is nothing to suggest they are not. The script editor does appear minimal yes but still functional.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is almost 6 years late but, in VB and VBA, simply start with the form name. (And if that doesn't work, just keep going up a parent object and you'll get there.) So, your code becomes:

```
Sub example()
If MYFORMNAME.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
     MsgBox("Checkbox 1 is checked.")
End If
End Sub
```

Of course, after typing "MYFORMNAME." you'll know if it will work because typomatic will kick in when the system recognizes "MYFORMNAME" after you hit the period.